Can I initialize an InfluxDB v2 database with a script, without using a GUI?
In the documentation for InluxDB v2, there are 3 different ways to bootstrap an InfluxDB database with authentication enabled: Using the Influx CLI tool, using the HTTP API, and using the browser based GUI. However, on the topic of creating the first "operator" authorization token, all three methods eventually point to the same way of doing it: Launch a browser and copy paste the token.
Searching on StackOverflow and similar third party sources, and asking on Twitter, don't yield any additional advice.
My question is... Accepting that InfluxDB really was designed to require use of a browser as a very first step in the installation process... How do people usually automate deployments? Also, how do you deal with firewalls? Especially in the common case where InfluxDB is deployed in the cloud and my web browser is not.
Things I tried + workarounds
I spent a couple days reading the influxdb documentation, convinced there must be a way to initialize the auth token without using a browśer.
As a result, it's not possible to automate fully unattended deployments of influxdb. Also the port 8086 must be open in the firewall so that I can connect with my browser.

So you can do just about anything in InfluxDB using CLI and APIs without needing the UI once you have passed the authentication stage. For automating deployment, you can use that by using Docker
